# Archiving iOS with x86_64 while using Macro

Tags: ios, appium, e2e-testing

I'm having my iOS app that we archive using xcode build with destination generic/platform=iOS

`xcodebuild -scheme MyApp -archivePath "./build/MyApp.xcarchive" -sdk iphonesimulator archive -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator'`

It was working fine till I added new swift Macro library.
then it start give me

> external macro implementation type 'Library.MockableMacro' could not be found for macro 'Mockable()'

I need to archive this way, cause i'm using this .app file produced directly in appium simulator for E2E testing.

I tried to build using
`-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone'`
and it compiled but it was crashing on simulator after installing it.

Is there another way for archiving for x64 bit into 86_64 archs or any other solution I may missed to achieve the result intended?